# Mono profiler changes execution of program in unexpected way

Tags: c#, f#, mono, profiling

I have written a program in C#. It makes uses of F# maps.

The program runs fine, without errors. However, when I try to profile it with:

```
mono --profile=log:report Program.exe
```

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Object is not a Bar 
 at Test.Bar.CompareTo (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 at 
 Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives+HashCompare.GenericCompare$cont@923-1       
(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.GenericComparer comp, System.Object yobj, System.Object xobj,   
IComparable x, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives+HashCompare.GenericCompare 
(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.GenericComparer comp, System.Object xobj, System.Object yobj)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at 
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives
+HashCompare.GenericComparisonWithComparerIntrinsic[Bar] 
(IComparer comp, Test.Bar x, Test.Bar y) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at   
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives+HashCompare.GenericComparisonIntrinsic[Bar]
(Test.Bar x, Test.Bar y) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives+-cctor@2099-1[Test.Bar].Compare 
(Test.Bar   x, Test.Bar y) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.MapTreeModule.add[Bar,Foo] (IComparer`1
comparer, Test.Bar k, Test.Foo v, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.MapTree`2
m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.MapTreeModule.mkFromEnumerator[Bar,Foo] 
(IComparer`1 comparer, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.MapTree`2 acc, IEnumerator`1 e)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.MapTreeModule.ofSeq[Bar,Foo] (IComparer`1   
comparer, IEnumerable`1 c) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpMap`2[Test.Bar,Test.Foo]..ctor 
(IEnumerable`1 elements) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

It seems that only when I run the program with the profiler, the method CompareTo(object obj) of class Bar is called to, with something that does not appear to be Bar.

That method is implemented by:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj) 
{
    if (obj == null) return 1;

    Bar otherBar = obj as Bar;
    if (otherBar != null) 
        return this.CompareTo(otherBar);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Bar!");
}
```

As said above, without the profiling, this error does not occur.

mono --version gives:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.5 (Debian 2.10.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
       TLS:           __thread
       SIGSEGV:       altstack
       Notifications: epoll
       Architecture:  x86
       Disabled:      none
       Misc:          softdebug 
       LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
       GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

update:

```
mono --profile=log:sample Program.exe
mono --profile=log:nocalls Program.exe
```

both work. However, I would like to get the standard profiler to work too.

Is this a bug in Mono, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The mono profiler does not play well with F# code generally, often giving weird error messages.  In F# inlining some functions occasionally fixes things.

Comment: You may try to use sampling profiler (``--profile=log:sample``), which is also less intrusive.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski Thanks. I indeed tried the sampling profiler, and it works. However, I would like to get the standard profiler to work as well.

Comment: I see. Then probably the best you could do is to file a bug.

Comment: As a side note, `Equals()` should never throw exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx

Comment: Also, if you use `fsi` you can get some simple profiling information with `#time "on";;`

Comment: @JohnPalmer Note that I am trying to profile a C# program (that uses F#-maps), therefore I cannot use fsi.

Comment: @Jan-Willem - well I think you are probably a bit stuck why do you need to use F# maps in particular, if you need the profiling you might be better off with `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>` which should play fine with the profiler.

Comment: @JohnPalmer - I use F# maps because I need immutable maps for my application. Dictionaries are mutable.

Comment: @Jan-Willem I realize it's sort of cold comfort but you're working with some fairly cutting edge stuff.  You may be the first person to actually try this particular application of this combination of technologies.  Therefore, I'd try to isolate a small, repeatable test case (sounds like you have) and file a bug with the mono folks.

Comment: Have you considered using valgrind - you may be able to get some perf info out of cachegrind - cache misses etc

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official page of F# for cross-platform packages](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FSharpLinux&referringTitle=Home) you should use Mono 2.10.9 or higher.

So try to upgrade mono first.

Comment: I upgraded to mono 2.11. However, I get exactly the same problem when trying to profile the program...